# SSIS Lookup component only returns matching rows when using partial mode

Tags: ssis

I am attempting to use a lookup transformation in my data transformation package and all of the other lookup transformations went well but one component returns the matching rows only when I enable the partial cache mode. If I use the full cache mode, all data is routed to the error path. I am using SQL 2005 SSIS. Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like it could be a collation issue, but if all the rows are being routed, I'm not so sure.

Anyway, if it is, here's some stuff you need to know:

Lookup actually has three modes, full, partial, and no cache.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140827154649/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/michen/archive/2007/10/03/ssis-lookups-modes.aspx)

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128000438/http://www.geekswithblogs.net/dtotzke/archive/2007/02/06/105585.aspx)

When there is no caching, the database is effectively doing the matching (using the database collation).  When there is caching, the lookup component is doing the matching (using a case-sensitive collation).

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Actually the problem was not about case-sensitivity. I made a join with all lower case chars and it didn't work. Once I changed both keys to all UPPER case, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation of why this is happening:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137820.aspx

Comment: I can't see anything in this article to explain the problem

Comment: @Tom The first 100 words is basically the answer you accepted.